# CSS vertical text alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a div, which contains an image and a span.  I would like the text in the span to be middle-aligned with the image.  Naturally, I made a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYbwf/)** for your convenience.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="legend">
    <img src="http://fate.holmes-cj.com/plus.png"/>
    <span> * 5</span>
</div>
```

Here are some of the things I've tried:

- `span {vertical-align:middle;}` seems to do nothing.
- `span {vertical-align:top;}` aligns the text to the top of the image.  You would think that if `top` works, so would `middle`.
- `span {vertical-align:20px;}` gives me what I want, but it depends upon (and interacts with) the div height, the image height, and the font size.
- adding `display:table-cell` has been suggested elsewhere on SO, but seems to do nothing in Chrome.

You can see the problem in context at my [Fate Dice Roller](http://fate.holmes-cj.com/).  Click on "roll" a few times, and then mouse over the histogram.  You get some neat stats on your dice rolls, but the text portion is misaligned.

Am I just out of luck here, or is vertical alignment really supposed to be this messy? I would love a solution that doesn't have to be tweaked when I change the font size.

Comment: Welcome to the joys of CSS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/nYbwf/3/

Just `vertical-align: middle` on the image element, that way it will align vertically right in the middle instead of baseline.

Comment: Yes, vertical-align: middle is a bit weird, it aligns with the text really. See http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/  "About the Value “middle”"