# vertical-align of a TD works in HTML not CSS

Tags: html, css

Well, this worked as expected:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">some text</td>
```

(the text comes out vertically and horizontally centered), so being a nice guy I moved over the style part into a CSS like so:

HTML:

```
<td class="allcenter">some text</td>
```

CSS:

```
.allcenter {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

and you know what, it only gets horizontally centered.

What gives?

Comment: have you tried googling....atleast 50 question on SO itself exists on this topic!!!! :)

Comment: How can you expect it to align if height is not assigned? http://jsfiddle.net/cedLr/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS vertical text alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535788/css-vertical-text-alignment)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Yy7Tt/6/

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhTz7/

Comment: @Mr.Alien, "td" is a block element and has a computed height.

Comment: @NoobEditor, yes i tried. They were all related to why 'vertical-align' does not work on inline elements whose height is neither fixed on computed like for block elements. And there were more than 50 too.

Comment: @geedubb, it is not a duplicate for the reason described in the comment immediately above this.

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian and nkmol: thank you for your constructive replies. StackOverflow is useful because of people like you.

Comment: @user2959502 td is not a block level element, also, if you don't have enough content, td will take up the space to the content it stores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="allcenter">some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding : 10px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
.allcenter {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy7Tt/8/)**